# Schematic fiber of $\mathbb{C}^2/\mu_2$ at $0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

I wanned to have a confirmation from you guys concerning a basic computation of the schematic fiber of $\mathbb{C}^2/\mu_2$ at $0$ where $\mu_2$ is the cyclic group in two elements so $\{1,-1\} \subset \mathbb{C}^*$.
I have found that it is the variety associated to the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$ is that correct ?
Thanks in advance for your answers,
Best rhylx

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: @AlanMuniz please answer in the answers, not the comments. If for some reason you find it uncomfortable (sometimes this happens to me when the answer is just "yes, that's right"), you can make your post community-wiki to avoid it counting for your reputation and things like that.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, I added a little more and made an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. Computing $$\mathbb{C}[x,y] \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2,xy]}\mathbb{C}$$
with $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2,xy]) $ being the origin gives $\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x^2,y^2,xy)}$.